# Is this the right way to add days to NSDate using NSDateComponents?

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I am using below method to add or subtract days from an NSDate.

When I logged the values I get an unexpected result at times.

Here is one of the case:

```
//This adds X days to the current Date and returns to the user
+(NSDate*)getRelativeDateInDays:(NSInteger)days forDate:(NSDate*)date{


    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [weekdayComponents setDay:days];
    NSDate *newDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:weekdayComponents toDate:date options:0];
    [gregorian release];
    [weekdayComponents release];
    NSLog(@"start Date : %@ End Date %@",date,newDate);
```

return newDate;
}

**CASE 1:**

2012-02-17 06:28:14.474 Application[2906:707] start Date : 2012-03-08 11:26:23 +0000 End Date 2012-03-09 11:26:23 +0000 Number of days 1

**CASE 2:**

2012-02-17 06:29:00.631 Application[2906:707] start Date : 2012-03-10 11:26:23 +0000 End Date 2012-03-11 10:26:23 +0000 Number of days 1

In case 1, when I added a single day to 2012-03-08 11:26:23 +0000, I get 2012-03-09 11:26:23 +0000.

But when I add a single day to  2012-03-10 11:26:23 +0000 I get   2012-03-11 10:26:23 +0000.

**1 hour is additionally reduced.** What could be the problem here?
Is any one have faced this problem?

Answer (score 2):

It's because of daylight savings times - US daylight savings starts on 11th March.

Edit:

You can solve it by converting the inputted date into a date components object, change the day component (time is unaffected) and then convert back into an `NSDate`.